# Display live Date + Time in Javascript in 1 line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I ran this command

```
$("#dateTime").text(new Date().toLocaleString());
```

I see this, `2/21/2020, 10:29:14 AM`

I want to my time to increase per second , so I tried

```
setInterval($("#dateTime").text(new Date().toLocaleString()), 1000);
```

I kept getting

[image]

> VM1104:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: please don't **close** this question, this is a way to do it in 1 line. Sometimes, the answer to this post exactly what people need.

Comment: Doing it in one line is not the issue, passing a string in stead of a function reference is. How the function reference is created is a different issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `$("#dateTime").text(new Date().toLocaleString()` in a function. `setInterval` function expect `function` as first argument.

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval(). This method is defined by the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin.

```
var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay);
```

**Parameters**

> **func:**
>   A function to be executed every delay milliseconds. The function is not passed any arguments, and no return value is expected.
>
> **code:**
>   An optional syntax allows you to include a string instead of a function, which is compiled and executed every delay milliseconds. This syntax is not recommended for the same reasons that make using eval() a security risk.
>
> **delay:**
>   The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should delay in between executions of the specified function or code. See Delay restrictions below for details on the permitted range of delay values.

**Working Example**

```js
setInterval(() => $("#dateTime").text(new Date().toLocaleString()), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dateTime"></div>
```

You could read more about setInterval [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)